# How to display list of numbers based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to get the list of numbers based on two condition

- number should be divisible by 3
- number should not end with 3
  How to implement the list within 50 numbers in javascript

Expected Output

6,9,12,15...45

My attempt

```js
function getNumbers() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      return
    } else {
      result.push(i);
      return result.toString()
    }
  }
}

console.log(getNumbers())
```

Comment: why isn't 6 in your expected output? it's divisible by 3 and doesn't end by 3.

Comment: Divisible by 3 but you expect 5 as an output?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work to specs -  your specs says it should start at 6 and not at 1

```js
const numbers = [...Array(50).keys()].
  filter(num => num !== 0 && num%3 === 0 && !String(num).endsWith("3"))

console.log(numbers)
```

NOTE: You can change `[...Array(50).keys()]` to `[...Array(50).keys()].slice(1)` if you want to avoid the test for 0

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a check if the modulo of 3 is 0 and the modulo of 10 is not 3. If you want to beautify the code you can combine this answer with mplungjan answer, but i wanted to show a mathematical alternative of the `!String(num).endsWith("3")` method provided by mplungjan.

I started your iteration at 1 instead of 0 to avoid 0 being put into the array. I also corrected your return statements.

```js
function getNumbers() {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 10 !== 3) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(getNumbers())
```